# Running analyses within mice after adding columns to the imputed datasets

Tags: r, r-mice

I multiple imputed 100 datasets by using `mice` in `R`, I then pooled them by using the mice command `compute` in order to run some oder operations on the pooled datasets. The result of this operations is an additional column to the pooled dataset.

Now I would like to "come back" within the mice framework to run analyses such as regression by using `with.mids`.

How can I "de-pool" my *datasets + the new column* in order to get a `mids` object to use with `with.mids`?

Could it be a solution to create a `mids` object by using the  `as.mids` function and then the `with` `mice` command?

Thanks a lot.

Emanuela